# foreach loop with first value of array

Tags: php, wordpress, loops, foreach

I have a custom WordPress metabox where I upload a file.
Only the location is saved to the database and the file(csv) is saved to the server.
With the help of fgetcsv I send the csv to the page (front-end)

I want to be able to have multiple files on one page. 
So I created (with the help of the interwebs) dynamic fields to add only if necessary.
The file is saved to the database with the help of `wp_upload_bits` which means that there is an array saved with the file name and the file url. So, to echo them I use: `$file['file']` or $file['url']

Now the problem:
There is a foreach loop that echo's all the uploades files for the sake of dynamics to add and remove fields.
Because the array is saved the the database with `wp_upload_bits` I always get two outputs (file and url) and I only want file.

Here is the code.
I can't seem to figure it out:

```
<?php 
$file = get_post_meta(get_the_ID(), 'meta_box_csv', true);
$c = 0;
$i = 0;
if ( count( $file['file'] ) > 0 ) {
    foreach( $file as $csv ) {
        if ( isset( $csv['file']) ) {
            printf( '<p><input type="file" id="meta_box_csv_'.$i.'" name="meta_box_csv_'.$c.'" value="'.$csv['file'].'" size="15" /><span class="remove">Remove</span> </p>' );
            $c = $c +1;
            $i = $i +1;
        }
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: So your code works, its just that you don't need the `$file['url']` part and want to get rid of it?

Comment: Hm interesting. I haven't thought of that. I have a problem with the foreach $file because it takes the entire array.... How would you do this. Just empty the value of the url?

Comment: I'm actually still not sure what part is broken. Does your code work?

Comment: The code works that's not the problem, sorry if I was unclear. The problem is that if a file gets saved it places two values in the db in an array named: file and url. If the foreach runs it outputs the file and the url. I only want the file to output. Hope this is more clear

Comment: I'm not seeing how `url` gets rendered in the above code snippet. You are only ever referencing `file` so it shouldn't be.

Comment: My point exactly. I only want to see the `file` but I keep seeing the `url` too

Comment: Can you post the contents of `print_r( $file );`

Comment: `echo '<pre>'.print_r($file,1);` results to:
Array
(
    [file] => /home/xxx/domains/xxx.nl/public_html/testcase/content/uploads/2014/08/test5.csv
    [url] => http://testcase.xxx.nl/content/uploads/2014/08/test5.csv
)

Comment: FYI: While debugging I found that if I do: `echo $file['url']` outside the foreach it only gives me the url. If I do this inside the foreach `echo $csv['url']` it spits out `/h`. /h is the start of file?????? I'm lost

Answer (score 0):

According to the dump you provided, `$file` represents just a single file not a collection of files, so there's nothing to `foreach` over. You should be able to just check `isset($file['file'])` then `printf` using `$file['file']` instead of `$csv['file']`

```
<?php 
$file = get_post_meta(get_the_ID(), 'meta_box_csv', true);
$c = 0;
$i = 0;

if ( isset( $file['file']) ) {
    printf( '<p><input type="file" id="meta_box_csv_'.$i.'" name="meta_box_csv_'.$c.'" value="'.$file['file'].'" size="15" /><span class="remove">Remove</span> </p>' );
    $c = $c +1;
    $i = $i +1;
}
```

Comment: Hmmm.. I'll take a look at this. The thing is that the user will be able to add more files to the array... then it should be foreach'ing

Comment: I get what you're going for, but if `$file` isn't an array of files then you need to fix something else. Have you every looked into the plugin Advanced Custom Fields? It makes this whole thing so much simpler.

Comment: Nope. Will take a look. Thnx for your effort. Dank je!